# Clustering based on co-occurrences

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

I would like to cluster data based on the co-occurrences keyword using R. I have encountered 2 difficulties compared to [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616703/simulating-co-occurrence-data-in-r).

1. The words are of different hierarchy levels
2. The keywords do not necessarily show in the order or the hierarchy level

Example

```
Keywords
Food;Fruit;Banana
Food;Fruit;Apple
Fruit;Food;Orange
Food;Bread;Toast
Food;Bread;Whole Grain
Bed;Bedroom;Furniture
Furniture;Bedroom;Bed
Furniture;Living Room;Chair
Furniture;Bedroom;Chair
```

I would like the result to be that keywords branch into Food and Furniture on the first level. On the second and third  there are further subbranches e.g. Bedroom, Living Room. If I use hierarchical cluster analysis like

```
hc <- hclust(dist(data))
plot(hc)
```

I would end up with "Furniture" as one of the categories on the lowest level, but it is a "nodal point" in my example.

Is there a function to solve this?

Best
Pete

Comment: I don't understand what your desired output is. What is the `data` that you are running `hclust` on? Are you asking about statistical methods for clustering? Are you just trying to reshape the data?

Comment: I am trying to find a method to run on the keywords. The output should be a tree or something similar. In this example the method should identify that food and furniture are overarching categories. "fruit" and "bread" are subordinate of "food" and there are 3 categories below fruit namely "apple", "banana" and "orange". Is there such a method that can do this?

Comment: "Find a method to run on the keywords" still isn't very specific. It sounds like maybe you want to turn this into an object that represents a tree or graph, but the specific functions available to you after you've made the conversion are very different.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but maybe not what you are looking for:

```
df <- read.csv2(header=F, comment.char="#", text="
Food;Fruit;Banana
Food;Fruit;Apple
#Fruit;Food;Orange
Food;Bread;Toast
Food;Bread;Whole Grain
#Bed;Bedroom;Furniture
Furniture;Bedroom;Bed
#Furniture;Living Room;Chair
Furniture;Bedroom;Chair")

library(data.tree)
df$pathString <- with(df, paste("root", V1, V2, V3, sep="/"))
dt <- as.Node(df)
dt
#                  levelName
# 1  root                   
# 2   ¦--Food               
# 3   ¦   ¦--Fruit          
# 4   ¦   ¦   ¦--Banana     
# 5   ¦   ¦   °--Apple      
# 6   ¦   °--Bread          
# 7   ¦       ¦--Toast      
# 8   ¦       °--Whole Grain
# 9   °--Furniture          
# 10      °--Bedroom        
# 11          ¦--Bed        
# 12          °--Chair
```

Have a look at the `data.tree` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is **not resembling cluster analysis**.

Do the following:

1. Count the frequency of each term.
2. Sort each row by term frequency, descending.
3. Insert each row into a tree.

The tree will branch into the most frequent terms, which have the more specific terms underneath.

No analysis happening here except counting + sorting by frequency - so nothing advanced or fancy but straightforward.